# Something wrong with my fft() in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

I have a function I am supposed to plot the amplitude spectrum of between 10MHz and 11.4MHz.  This is the function:  cos(6.72*(10**7*t) + 3.2*sin(5*(10**5*t)))  I know what the plot is supposed to look like, but mine is completely wrong.  I'm pretty sure it's a programming error, not a math/theory error because I'm doing exactly what a MatLab example is showing, but I feel like Python is doing something I'm not understanding.  I'm supposed to sample this function 8192 times at 10ns apart, multiply it by a Hamming window, and plot the amplitude spectrum in dB between 10MHz and 11.4MHz.  The carrier (10.7MHz) should be around 55 dB.  The second pair of sidebands is the greatest amplitude at 60 dB.  Then, the fifth pair of sidebands is the 20 dB point, so around 40 dB.  Can anyone spot something wrong with this code that explains why mine doesn't show this?

```
import numpy
import scipy
import scipy.fftpack
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import pi
import pylab
from pylab import *
import cmath
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

samples = 8192

#Defining the test function
t = scipy.linspace(0.01, 32/390625, samples, False)   #Sample samples times at 10ns apart
#The samples is non-inclusive, it goes from 0 to samples-1.
x_t = cos(6.72*(10**7*t) + 3.2*sin(5*(10**5*t)))  #Define x(t)
acc = lambda t: (x_t)                             #Define x[t] in terms of t as a variable in Python's eyes 

signal = acc(t)                 #Make signal a function of t
plt.subplot(211)                #Set up a plot
plt.xlabel('Ohmega (Hz)')       #Label x axis
plt.ylabel('Amplitude of sampled x(t) (dB)')  #Label y axis

window = numpy.hamming(samples)    #Make a hamming window 


w = scipy.linspace(0, 100*10**6, samples, False)   #Create Ohmega between 1/(10ns)
signal = signal * window        #Multiply by the hamming window
signal = scipy.fft(signal)      #Take the FFT
signal = abs(20*log10(signal))  #Get the magnitude in dB scale

plt.xlabel('Ohmega')            #Label x axis
plt.ylabel('|F[w]|')            #Label y axis
#marker, stemlines, baseline = stem(w,signal, 'b-..')    #Plot with stemlines
plot(w,signal, 'b-')
plt.xlim(10*10**6, 11.4*10**6)  #Set x-limits

plt.show()                      #Show the plot
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

My code now:

```
import numpy
import scipy
import scipy.fftpack
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import pi
import pylab
from pylab import *
import cmath
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

samples = 8192

#Defining the test function
t = scipy.linspace(0.01, 32/390625, samples, False)         #Sample samples times at 10ns apart
#The samples is non-inclusive, it goes from 0 to samples-1.
x_t = cos(6.72*(10**7*t) + 3.2*sin(5*(10**5*t)))            #Define x(t)
acc = lambda t: cos(6.72*(10**7*t) + 3.2*sin(5*(10**5*t)))  #Define x[t] in terms of t as a variable in Python's eyes 

#signal = acc(t)                 #Make signal a function of t
plt.subplot(211)                #Set up a plot
plt.xlabel('Ohmega (Hz)')       #Label x axis
plt.ylabel('Amplitude of sampled x(t) (dB)')  #Label y axis

window = numpy.hamming(samples)    #Make a hamming window 


w = scipy.linspace(0.01, 100*10**6, samples, False)   #Create Ohmega between 1/(10ns)
signal = lambda t: abs(20*log10(scipy.fft(acc*window)))
#acc = acc * window        #Multiply by the hamming window
#acc = scipy.fft(acc)      #Take the FFT
#acc = abs(20*log10(acc))  #Get the magnitude in dB scale

plt.xlabel('Ohmega')            #Label x axis
plt.ylabel('|F[w]|')            #Label y axis
#marker, stemlines, baseline = stem(w,signal, 'b-..')    #Plot with stemlines

plot(w,signal, 'b-')
plt.xlim(10*10**6, 11.4*10**6)  #Set x-limits

plt.show()                      #Show the plot
```

And the error...:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hollis/Documents/ELEN 322/ELEN_322_#2.py", line 39, in <module>
    plot(w,signal, 'b-')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2467, in plot
    ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 3893, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 322, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 300, in _plot_args
    x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 240, in _xy_from_xy
    raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

While I've seen and fixed this error before, I have no idea how to fix it now.  Apparently a signal sampled 8192 times and the variable determining where it was sampled are different dimensions.  I'm so lost on this one...

Comment: 32/390625 == 0, it's integer division. Write 32.0/390625

Answer (score 1):

Your error might come from the way you define `x(t)` :

```
x_t = cos(6.72*(10**7*t) + 3.2*sin(5*(10**5*t)))  #Define x(t)
acc = lambda t: (x_t)  #Define x[t] in terms of t as a variable in Python's eyes
```

When Python executes the first line, it assigns to the variable x_t the value of the formula you're given it using the current value of t ( `scipy.linspace(0.01, 32/390625, samples, False)` ). It doesn't interpret `t` as a variable.

To fix this change the second line by this :

```
acc = lambda t: cos(6.72*(10**7*t) + 3.2*sin(5*(10**5*t)))
```

**EDIT :** Just noticed you did the same with `signal`. Writing : `signal = acc(t)` (even if you fixed `acc`) will just assign the result of the function `acc(t)` (with the current value of t) to the variable signal. It won't be a function. (Why don't you just use acc instead of signal as acc is a function of t anyway ?)

Comment: That makes sense, but it still isn't working. I'm essentially seeing a horizontal line at 20 dB if that helps in anything...

Comment: Please read my edit. (You're doing the same with signal so signal is a constant value and not a function)

Comment: This gives me all kinds of errors... Can't multiply by window because illegal operation "*" of function and float, it won't take the fft() of acc:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hollis/Documents/ELEN 322/ELEN_322_#2.py", line 31, in <module>
    acc = scipy.fft(acc)      #Take the FFT
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/fft/fftpack.py", line 164, in fft
    return _raw_fft(a, n, axis, fftpack.cffti, fftpack.cfftf, _fft_cache)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/fft/fftpack.py", line 48, in _raw_fft
    n = a.shape[axis]
IndexE tuple index out of range

Comment: Why would you do that : ``signal = lambda t: abs(20*log10(scipy.fft(acc*window)))`` ? Isn't ``acc`` supposed to be a function ?

Comment: Because it yells at me if I don't... Like I said, I'm not fully understanding something here.  What can I do to make this plot the amplitude spectrum?

Comment: I never really worked with scipy so just try to explain what you're trying to achieve with your code: what's supposed to be a function, etc. ; As I said earlier, in this line you're doing a product of a function (``acc``) and a float (``window``). Weren't you supposed to do something like ``acc(t)*window`` ? (otherwise, and again, signal wouldn't be a function but a constant)

Comment: Signal should be a function.  I'm trying to plot the amplitude spectrum of the original function, acc.  But every time I multiply anything by acc, it says I can't.  I can't take the fft() of it either because it says tuple index out of range.

Comment: Oh, and window is technically a function.  The hamming window is defined as a function, I don't know why it's a float...

Comment: Did you read my last comment ? (about how you don't use the `t` variable, unless you put `acc(t)` instead of `acc`) ; + I checked window ,and it should return an array (an ndarray to be precise) : numpy.hamming(samples) ; So you'd end up multiplying a number : `acc(t)` (probably float) by an array... Not sure that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: P.S. acc is the function, not acc(t).  I've figured that much out.  When using acc(t), I get the same output as I had to begin with.  acc however, is what is defined as the function...

Comment: No, that isn't what I wanted to do.  I need to multiply the funcion acc by the function of window.  Then change it do dB form, and take the abs()...  But for some reason my plot isn't coming out right.

Comment: You have to understand that you can't multiply a function by a function ! (especially when in your code, `window` isn't technically a function. It's a constant array); If you want that new function (signal) to be the product of two functions, you should have something like : `newFunction = lambda t : function1(t) * function2(t)`

Comment: As for what you're trying to achieve, ``hamming`` returns an array (which is your window) : do you want to multiply each value of that array by the result of `acc(t)` ?

Comment: Where are you finding that acc(t) is the function?  It returns as an array.  And acc returns as function <lambda> at 0xaddresshere.  I think you're missing the point of what I'm trying to accomplish here...  I need to multiply the window FUNCTION (.54 + .46cos(2pit/T)) by my original function acc (cos(6.72(10^7t)+3.2sin(5(10^5t)))) in order to make the final result appear better.  Then, I need the absolute value of the fft() of that.  No arrays (except w and t), no floats.

Comment: I'm not missing that point. I'm just telling you what you wrote and what I can understand, not what you were supposed to write (as I'm not that much into Fourier Transformations :-)). It's true `acc` is a function (lambda). But you declared window as follows : `window = numpy.hamming(samples)` ; So the variable `window` is definitely an array, not a function. Once you have something called `window` that is a function and those what you want, you'll have to replace `acc` by `acc(t)` and `window` by `window(t)` in the lambda declaration (because you want signal(t) = ... acc(t)*window(t) )

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still working on this.   I did found this post: [FFT in Matlab and numpy / scipy give different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680909/fft-in-matlab-and-numpy-scipy-give-different-results) which may shed some light.

The post suggest that use the transpose within Scipy as Matlab applies the fft over the columns of the matrix, numpy applies the fft over the last axis (the rows) by default

Hope that helps.